# In Ruby, what's the difference between String() and #to_s

Tags: ruby, coding-style

```
String(1.1) == (1.1).to_s    => true
String(1.1) === (1.1).to_s   => true
```

Is there a difference between these two coercion methods? If so, can you demonstrate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [docs for the `String` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-String) say:

> Converts arg to a String by calling its to_s method.

So generally they are the same, but there are some differences – although you’re unlikely to see them for real. `String()` checks the class of its parameter, and if it’s not already a `String` then calls `to_s` on it. Calling `to_s` directly means the method is called regardless.

Consider the class:

```
class MyString < String
  def to_s
    "Overridden to_s method"
  end
end
```

An instance of `MyString` is already a `String` object, so passing it as a parameter to `String()` won’t do anything. Calling `to_s` on it will however return `Overridden to_s method`.

```
1.9.3p286 :010 > m = MyString.new 'my string'
 => "my string" 
1.9.3p286 :011 > o = String.new 'orig string'
 => "orig string" 
1.9.3p286 :012 > String o
 => "orig string" 
1.9.3p286 :013 > String m
 => "my string" 
1.9.3p286 :014 > o.to_s
 => "orig string" 
1.9.3p286 :015 > m.to_s
 => "Overridden to_s method"
```

You’re unlikely ever to need to override `to_s` on a `String` subclass like this, in general you can treat `String()` and `to_s` as the same, but it might be useful to know what’s going on.

Comment: RE overriding #to_s: As of Ruby 2.0.0 the docs clarify the behavior: "First tries to call its to_str method, then its to_s method.". This is why overriding #to_s has no effect -- because Ruby first invokes .to_str on the MyString object, which hasn't been overridden in the example above.

Answer (score 5):

They raise different exceptions when they fail:

```
bo = BasicObject.new

String(bo)
TypeError: can't convert BasicObject into String

bo.to_s
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_s' for #<BasicObject:0x0003efbfd79c10>
```

Answer (score 3):

String(object) is a Kernel method that calls #to_s on the object